# \OauthClients' not found

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-passport

i am working on laravel 5.8, and I try to execute this code :

```
 public function testOauthLogin() {
        $oauth_client_id = env('PASSPORT_CLIENT_ID');
        $oauth_client = OauthClients::findOrFail($oauth_client_id);

        $body = [
            'username' => 'admin@admin.com',
            'password' => 'admin',
            'client_id' => $oauth_client_id,
            'client_secret' => $oauth_client->secret,
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'scope' => '*'
        ];
        $this->json('POST','/oauth/token',$body,['Accept' => 'application/json'])
             ->assertStatus(200)
             ->assertJsonStructure(['token_type','expires_in','access_token','refresh_token']);
    }
```

but i get the following error

```
Error : Class 'Tests\Feature\Auth\AuthController\OauthClients' not found
```

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: add OauthClientsname space

Comment: you have an idea of his path

Comment: try to invoke OauthClients as preprocessor directives

Answer (score 0):

Add `use App\OauthClients` on top of your `AuthController` file where the other `use` statements are.

Answer (score 0):

for future lurkers - use different model

`\Laravel\Passport\Client::findOrFail()`

instead of `OauthClients`